# Why consider a rotating ball about a circular track as a point object?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

Consider a small ball of mass $m$ translating along a circular track:

[image: Ball on track]

As the body reaches the top most part of the circular track, we say that the minimum value of the velocity of the centre of mass of the small ball must be:

$$ v = \sqrt{gR} $$

where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity and $R$ is the radius of the circular track. Now, this result is derived for a point mass $m$ going about the circle. But, a small ball is not a point object, then how come this same equation is also used for a small ball of mass $m$ moving in a circle of radius $R$? Or is this an approximation as the ball is much smaller compared to the radius of circular track?

Comment: Yes it is just a good approximation.

Comment: @trula , ok, thanks

Comment: The key assumption here is that the size of the ball is much smaller compared to the radius of the circular track. This means that the ball's dimensions do not significantly affect the dynamics of the motion. If the size of the ball becomes comparable to the radius of the track, then the motion would need to be analyzed differently, taking into account the ball's dimensions and potential rolling motion, but for many practical cases, the point mass approximation is sufficient.

Comment: @Timmetje , can you show mathematically, how the dimensions of the ball can be ignored  like say if the ball were comparable to the radius of the circular track, then how would we analyze its motion? I guess suitable approximations can then be applied on these results for a ball much smaller than the radius of the circular track, to obtain the result that the ball can be treated as a point object.